# scrolling not smooth in ios phonegap

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, phonegap

i'm building a phonegap(cordova) application and it is working great for android, but there is some scrolling issue with iOS build i-e i cannot scroll smoothly.

Anyone else faces the same issue, share your knowledge and experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add "  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"
but there is some bugs with it

Comment: This is more like a comment not an answer.